# how to obtain the index of non zero element for each column in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have a matrix

```
In [241]: coefs1
Out[243]: 
array([[  0.00000000e+00,   1.50237061e+00,   1.78732321e+00,
          3.07772735e+00,   3.07813831e+00,   3.10868249e+00,
          3.11535120e+00,   3.12940442e+00,   3.13184569e+00],
       [  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   2.47275798e-01,
          1.09915105e+00,   1.09941361e+00,   1.11107569e+00,
          1.10996973e+00,   1.11455077e+00,   1.11611816e+00],
       [  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,   5.40736015e-04,   3.14102933e-02,
          2.94126207e-02,   3.73186676e-02,   3.98861164e-02],
       [  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,  -5.68298896e-02,  -7.37245112e-02],
       [  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
          1.89362500e+00,   1.89420071e+00,   1.92348705e+00,
          1.95920304e+00,   2.02228837e+00,   2.04170329e+00],
       [  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         -5.14869801e-02,  -1.09548801e-01,  -1.24983238e-01],
       [  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   3.69385511e-02,
          7.49599293e-02,   1.13349454e-01,   1.29144575e-01],
       [  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,  -1.06357967e-02]])
```

I would like to obtain for each column the index of the non 0 elements. I want explicitly the index like [1,2,4] and not [True,True,False,True].

I have tried different combinations all similar to:

```
In [244]: np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: [i for i,val in enumerate(x) if val!=0], arr=coefs1, axis=0)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-253-f2fcb4de54a9> in <module>()
----> 1 np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: [i for i,val in enumerate(x) if val!=0], arr=coefs1, axis=0)

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/shape_base.py in apply_along_axis(func1d, axis, arr, *args)
    115             i.put(indlist, ind)
    116             res = func1d(arr[tuple(i.tolist())],*args)
--> 117             outarr[tuple(i.tolist())] = res
    118             k += 1
    119         return outarr

ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 2 to array axis with dimension 0
```

but I obtain always some kind of error. 
Is there a quick solution to this problem?

EDIT :

Solution as argwhere works fine on 1 dimensional array.

```
In [293]: np.argwhere(coefs1[:,2] != 0)
Out[293]: 
array([[0],
       [1]])
```

But how can I apply this function to each column of my matrix? 
As if my column were all independent vectors.

Comment: Have you looked at [np.argwhere](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html)?

Comment: `i = np.argwhere(coefs1); i[i[:,0] == 0][:,1]` will give you what you want for your first column, `i[i[:,0] == 1][:,1]` for your second, etc.

Comment: I have found temporary solution l=[np.argwhere(coefs1[:,i]!=0) for i in range(coefs1.shape[1])] but I think that both our solutions are ugly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a builtin that handles this, because to return an array all columns would have to have the same number of nonzeros, which is a very special case. The best you can do is presumably:

```
[np.flatnonzero(row) for row in coefs1.T]
```